# Can we compare result retrieved from query against a text file through Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to fetch data from a query and need to check the data presence in the extract. I have downloaded the extract to local

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) for this like:

1. Add Response Assertion as a child of the request which returns the query result
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: JMeter Variable - variable, holding the query result i.e. `yourVariable`
   - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
   - Patterns to Test: `${__FileToString(/path/to/local/file,,)}`

[__FileToString() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) will read the file provided and the Response Assertion will compare it with the `${yourVariable}` value, if they will be equal - the sampler will be marked as passed, in case of differences it will be failed.

Example configuration:

[image: JMeter Response Assertion FileToString]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)